React Router routing doesn't work with MUI Drawer and Redux Toolkit
Using Material UI component Drawer with React Router, managing global state with Redux Toolkit. When i click on NavLinks in drawer it changes routes inconsistent. Sometimes it works, sometimes you need to click two times and sometimes i just doesn't change anything. What can be the problem?
Drawer.tsx
const navItems = [
  { name: "Home", path: "/" },
  { name: "Download", path: "/download" },
  { name: "Question", path: "/questions" },
  { name: "About", path: "/about" },
];

export default function Drawer() {
  const isOpen = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.drawer.isOpened);
  const drawerDispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <MuiDrawer open={isOpen} onClose={() => drawerDispatch(toggleDrawer())}>
      <Box sx={{ width: 250 }} role="presentation">
        <Typography
          variant="h6"
          component="div"
          sx={{
            ml: 2,
            mt: 1,
          }}
        >
          Page
        </Typography>
        <List>
          {navItems.map((navItem) => (
            <ListItem
              key={navItem.name}
              disablePadding
              onClick={() => drawerDispatch(toggleDrawer())}
            >
              <ListItemButton>
                <NavLink to={navItem.path}>
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={navItem.name}
                    sx={{ color: "text.primary" }}
                  />
                </NavLink>
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Box>
    </MuiDrawer>
  );
}

drawerSlice.ts
export interface DrawerState {
  isOpened: boolean;
}

const initialState: DrawerState = {
  isOpened: false,
};

export const drawerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "drawer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggle: (state) => {
      state.isOpened = !state.isOpened;
    },
  },
});


main.tsx
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
            <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/download" element={<DownloadPage />} />
            <Route path="/questions" element={<QuestionsPage />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ReduxProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

Tried adding and deleting onClick events for different items. Reviewing drawer slice and route logic. Adding stopPropagation to ListItem, so that event doesn't bubble up.

Sorry, it's not clear from this code what issue or problem you are referring to is. Please [edit] to clarify what the exact specific issue is, including exact reproduction steps you use to produce it. If possible, try to create a running Codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Ok, so i just figured out what the problem was. I was wrapping ListItemText with NavLink, which make only text navigatable, but not the ListItem. So, i just wrapped ListItem with NavLink and it works correct.
